# rewrite JavaScript When the time has already reached the next Bold

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set the JavaScript so that it marks the time automatically, but I can not bring to work. how can I rewrite the javascript:  For example now is 6:49 clock and automatically bold the nechste clock For example, it is automatically bold 7:32 clock.
and when the time 7:32 is automatically bold 8:01.
So when the time has already reached the next Bold

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var hour = new Date().getHours();

  $('table td:nth-child(1)').each(function(index, td) {
    if ($(td).text().indexOf(hour) == 00) {
      $(td).addClass('highlight-time');
    } else {
      $(td).removeClass('highlight-time');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight-time {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">6:49</td>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">BLERI-COM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">7:32</td>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">ENDRITI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">8:01</td>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">BEKA-KAQANIK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">8:21</td>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">MEDINA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px;width: 75px;">8:59</td>
      <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">METI-COMERC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <table>
        <tbody>
```

Comment: You need to run the checking routine every x seconds. Take a look at *setInterval()* on how to create a timer in Javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I do not know how to do that with javascript, I know my net so good :(

Answer (score 0):

One way is:
Put your Javascript code into a function. Then call that function after some time. Suppose I have all this code in a function width name setBold() and I want to call it after every three seconds then I will write this code

> var myVar=setInterval(function(){setBold()}, 3000);

In this way after every three seconds Javascript function setBold will call. You can change three second to one hour. Because you are going to bold text after getting hour.

So for one hour it will be :

> var myVar=setInterval(function(){setBold()}, (1000*60*60));

Comment: Thank you for your reply .I have tried it but I do not get it work I don't know why :(

Comment: first i tray to  writ in this Website http://jsfiddle.net/ when in this Website  work i add in my Website laike  this  <script type="text/javascript" src="...js/boldrajonal.js"></script> I had to insert so. otherwise there will not work in my Website only this way is to add this JavaScript to my Website